# Adding map services fails

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-service

Trying to add a map service form arcgis server to arcgis desktop, but what surprises me that I can add any layer " service " to the table of content except the Arial photos layer, see the screenshot .

[image]

What might be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to know which version of ArcGIS desktop and ArgGIS server that you are using, in my issue the maps was published using ArcGIS server 10.2 and I was trying to import the service in ArcGIS desktop 10.1 .
We have noticed that some maps cannot be imported if you are using a desktop version older than the server version.
the issue was solved when we tried to import the map service in ArcGIS 10.2.2